# Cannot set SKU using Quickbooks API

Tags: quickbooks-online

I’m trying to create an item using the Quickbooks Online API, but the field `Sku` is just ignored. I send a body like this:

```
{
  "TrackQtyOnHand": true, 
  "Name": "Garden Supplies",
  "Sku": "ITEM-1", 
  "QtyOnHand": 10, 
  "IncomeAccountRef": {
    "name": "Sales of Product Income", 
    "value": "79"
  }, 
  "AssetAccountRef": {
    "name": "Inventory Asset", 
    "value": "81"
  }, 
  "InvStartDate": "2015-01-01", 
  "Type": "Inventory", 
  "ExpenseAccountRef": {
    "name": "Cost of Goods Sold", 
    "value": "80"
  }
}
```

However in the object I get back as response, the `Sku` field is not there.

I set the parameter `minorVersion` to 45 (which is something I was suggested to do), but still not working.

Comment: Four years later, and I'm getting the error, "Property Sku does not exist". The form layout designer allows for a SKU column and enabling it does make it show up on invoices, but there's no way to enter a SKU when creating an invoice on the web site and there's nothing about a SKU in the API documentation for invoices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is that the param `minorVersion` should actually be `minorversion` (all lowercase).